# VueJS Facebook Authentication `withCrednetials` not working on production (Heroku)

Tags: facebook-authentication

I've been trying to implement Facebook authentication in my VueJs App (Hosted on Heroku, running on express.js in a docker container talking to a Rails backend hosted on a separate Heroku app).

In Vue I have the following method:

```js
export const handleFacebookLogin = async () => {
  try {
    const { data } = await instance.get(`users/auth/facebook/callback`, { withCredentials: true });

    await addTokenCookiesAxios(data);

    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
};
```

In development, I can see the request being sent to my backend has `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` set to true and Facebook authentication works as expected. However, in production, these headers don't seem to be sent and so authentication fails.

I can't seem to figure out what might be causing this.
Has anyone got any idea what might be the problem, or where I should be looking to try to find the error?